# How do I use savReaderWriter with pypy3, or is there a better alternative?

Tags: spss, dylib, pypy

So I managed to install savReaderWriter for pypy3, but when I try to read a file with `SavReader`, I get the following error:

```
OSError: Cannot load library /usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/7.3.1_1/libexec/site-packages/savReaderWriter/spssio/macos/libspssdio.dylib: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/7.3.1_1/libexec/site-packages/savReaderWriter/spssio/macos/libspssdio.dylib, 2): Symbol not found: _CFLocaleCopyCurrent
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/7.3.1_1/libexec/site-packages/savReaderWriter/spssio/macos//libspssdio.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/7.3.1_1/libexec/site-packages/savReaderWriter/spssio/macos//libspssdio.dylib
```

It appears the issue is `Symbol not found: _CFLocaleCopyCurrent`, but I have no idea how to fix this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work now with the latest pypy3 build.